# Get help for zsh builtin command (--help' does not work)

Tags: zsh, documentation

Why, unlike Bash, almost all Zsh executable's option of '--help' cannot work, what'd be its counterpart to help user doing on it ?

Comment: Make sure the manual is installed in `info` format, and run `info zsh read`, `info zsh zle`...

Answer (score 1):

TL,DR: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

I guess you're asking about help for zsh [builtins](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) (), since the `zsh` executable does understand `--help`.

The intended way to get help on a zsh builtin from within zsh is with the [`run-help` function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-run_002dhelp-1). Unfortunately, it is not enabled by default, although some distributions of zsh (e.g. Debian and derivatives including Ubuntu) enable it in the system `zshrc` file.

To make sure the `run-help` function is enabled, put this in your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
if ((${+aliases[run-help]})); then unalias run-help; fi
autoload -Uz run-help
```

By default, unless you're using vi editing mode, `run-help` is bound to the key combination `^[h`, i.e. <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This is true even without the lines above, but without them, `run-help` runs `man` directly, which doesn't work for builtins.

Start typing a command where the program name is a builtin or an executable, then press `^[h`. The cursor can be inside the command name or inside a parameter. This invokes `man`, but if the command is a zsh builtin, it shows the part of the zsh manual that documents that built-in. When you exit `man`, you get back the command line you were typing.

```
darkstar% alias -Esch
```

*Read the documentation of the `alias` builtin, then exit the man reader.*

```
darkstar% alias -
```

If you use vi editing mode, you'll also need to bind `run-help` to a key. To bind it to Alt+H in both insert and command mode, you can use

```
bindkey -M viins '^[h' run-help
bindkey -M vicmd '^[h' run-help
```

---

As to why `--help` doesn't work: `--help` was introduced and pushed by the GNU project, together with long options (`--foo`). Bash is a GNU component, so it naturally uses `--help` for help. Zsh is not a GNU component and it only supports short options (`--foo` is technically a grouping of the options `--`, `-f, and` -o` twice).

Comment: Assuming the user is using Vi key bindings, this seems to not work out of the box. What would that user need to do to get similar functionality?  Asking for a friend...

Comment: @Kusalananda `bindkey -e` or `bindkey -M viins 'whatever key you like' run-help; bindkey -M vicmd 'whatever key you like' run-help`

Comment: A Vi user may want to bind `'\C-h'` rather than something that relies on Esc, but that might just be me. Thanks.